# Invariant and coinvarant are isomorphic

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory, lie-algebras

> Let $V$ be a completely reducible representation of a lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$.
>
> Show that $V^{\mathfrak{g}} = \{ v \in V : \rho_{x}(v) = 0\}$ is isomorphic to $V_{\mathfrak{g}} = V / \mathfrak{g}V$, where $\mathfrak{g}V = \{ \rho_{x}(v) : x \in \mathfrak{g}, v \in V\}$

We have $V = \oplus_{i \in I} V_{i}$ where $V_{i}$ are irreducible. Do I have that $V = V^{\mathfrak{g}} \oplus (V^{\mathfrak{g}})^{c}$, and then would $V^{\mathfrak{g}} \hookrightarrow V \xrightarrow{\pi} V_{\mathfrak{g}}$ be an isomorphism? If so, where is the assumption of complete reducibility used?

Comment: The decomposition you state holds when $\mathfrak{g}$ is semisimple.

Answer (score 1):

For an irreducible representation $W$ we have two cases:

- $$ acts trivially on $W$, in which case $W^ = W$ and $ W = 0$.
- $$ acts non-trivially on $W$. In this case, $W^$ is a proper subrepresentation of $W$ and $ W$ is a non-zero subrepresentation of $W$. Consequently, $W^ = 0$ and $ W = W$ because $W$ is irreducible.

We also observe that for every representation $W$ and decomposition $W = \bigoplus_{i ∈ I} W_i$ into subrepresentations we have $W^ = \bigoplus_{i ∈ I} W_i^$ and $ W = \bigoplus_{i ∈ I}  W_i$.

Let now $V = ⨁_{i ∈ I} V_i$ be a decomposition into irreducible subrepresentations.
Let $J ⊆ I$ be the subset of all those indices $j$ for which $$ acts trivially on $V_j$.
We find that
$$
  V^ = \bigoplus_{i ∈ I} V_i^ = \bigoplus_{j ∈ J} V_j
$$
and that
$$
   V
  = \bigoplus_{i ∈ I}  V_i
  = \bigoplus_{i ∈ I \setminus J} V_i \,.
$$
It follows that
$$
  V /  V
  =
  \bigoplus_{i ∈ I} V_i
  \Bigg/\!\!
  \bigoplus_{i ∈ I \setminus J} V_i
  ≅
  \bigoplus_{j ∈ J} V_j
  =
  V^ \,.
$$